# Sets of infinite Hausdorff dimension in a second countable metric space

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces, hausdorff-measure, dimension-theory-analysis

> I am wondering if there exists an example of a second countable metric space $X$ containing a set $A$ with infinite Hausdorff dimension.

Comment: $L^p(\Bbb R)$, $p<\infty$.

Comment: @David C. Ullrich Can you elaborate?

Comment: Yes.  There is even a metric on the Cantor set so that the Hausdorff dimension is infinite.

Comment: @GEdgar can you tell me about this metric on the Cantor set? I know that the HausDim of the Cantor set with the euclidean metric is $\log2/\log3$

Comment: Well, $L^p(\Bbb R)$ is second-countable, being a separable metric space. And it contains subspaces homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$, so the dimension is $\ge n$ for every $n$.

Answer (score 2):

The infinite power $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is separable metrizable (hence second countable) and has infinite **inductive** dimension. This is a topologically defined notion, and is the smallest one among many related concepts; in particular, is [less or equal to the Hausdorff dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension#Hausdorff_dimension_and_inductive_dimension).

To see that $\mathrm{dim}\,\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}} = \infty$: It can be proved that the inductive dimension of a space is at least equal to the sup of the dimensions of its subspaces (see Engelking, *Dimension Theory*, 1.1.2), and that $\mathbb{R}^{n}$  for $n\in{\mathbb{N}}$ has inductive dimension $n$.

Comment: Thanks, but I don’t know anything about the inductive dimension

Comment: The space $\mathbb R^n$ (with $n$ a positive integer) has Hausdorff dimension $n$.  The above space (and Ullrich's space) contain (bi-Lipschitz equivalent) copies of $\mathbb R^n$.  Therefore the Hausdorff dimension of $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ is at least $n$.  Since this holds for all positive integers $n$, the Hausdorff dimension is infinite.

Comment: @GEdgar What is the metric you put on $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ so that it is 2nd-countable?

Comment: @Pedro Sánchez Terraf

Comment: @less There is a standard construction of a metric for a countable product of metric spaces $(X_n,d_n)$. Just take 
$$
d(x,y) := \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{d_n(x(n),y(n))}{2^n(1+d_n(x(n),y(n)))},
$$
where $x,y\in \prod_n X_n$.

Comment: @less I have expanded the answer according to your comments.

Comment: @Pedro Sánchez Terraf Thank you very much, although I have to say I would have preferred an argument which used directly the notion of Hausdorff dimension instead of a different one and comparing the two.

Comment: @GEdgar How do I prove that ℝ has Hausdorff dimension ? More generally how do I prove that if $$ is a borel set of positive measure then the Hausdorff dimension of $$ is $$? I know that $_()=_()>0$ implies $_()=+∞$ for all $<$; but how do I show that $_{\alpha}()=0$ for $\alpha>n$ ?